# Proving $3x^{10} - y^{10} = 1991$ has no integral solutions. Check my proof.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, diophantine-equations, alternative-proof

The problem is

> Prove that $$3x^{10} - y^{10} = 1991$$ has no integral solutions.

I have written this proof, of which I am not sure.

---

Assume that $x$ and $y$ are integers.
$$\begin{align}
3 x^{10}-y^{10} &\equiv 2 \mod 3 \\
\implies \qquad y^{10} &\equiv 2 \mod 3 \\
\implies \qquad y^{10} &= 3 m + 2, \text{where } m\in\mathbb{Z} \\[8pt]
\therefore \qquad 3x^{10}-y^{10} &=3x^{10}-3m-2=1991 \\[8pt]
\implies 3 \left(x^{10}-m\right) &= 1993
\end{align}$$

But $3\not\mid 1993$, $1993 = 3k+1$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$$\begin{align}
\implies& 3\left(x^{10}-m\right) = 3k+1 \\
\implies& x^{10}-m \;\text{is not an integer}
\end{align}$$

This contradicts our assumption that $x^{10}$, $m$ are integers, because if they were then $x^{10}-m$ would also be an integer, which [it] is not. Hence, our assumption is wrong, therefore the above equation does not have any integral solutions.

---

Please read my proof. If there are any errors, then please help in resolving them. Any other method of proof is also appreciated. But please tell if my proof is correct.

Comment: If you reduce your equation $\pmod 3$, you get $-y^{10}\equiv 2\pmod 3$, or $y^{10}\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: How does -y^19 congruent to 2 mod 3 change to y^10 congruent to 1 mod 3 ?

Comment: Assuming you meant $-y^{10}$, then just multiply both sides by $-1$.  Note that $-1\times 2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: Hint (for the original problem):  work $\pmod {11}$.

Comment: Just use lulu's hint and Fermat's little theorem. $\pmod{11}$ is pretty natural here

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But is my proof correct or not ?

Comment: What do you mean?  In my first comment I pointed out an algebraic error in your argument.

Comment: Sorry for that. So the approach is correct and if I correct that mistake the proof will also be correct ?

Comment: Why would you think that?  Your idea was sensible enough...you tried to reduce $\pmod 3$.  If it turned out that there was no solution $\pmod 3$, you'd be done.  But there is no problem finding a solution $\pmod 3$, so this approach fails (or at least it needs a lot more work.).  Really, though, working $\pmod {11}$ is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof fails at the very first step; you wrote down the implication
$$3 x^{10}-y^{10} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}\qquad
\implies \qquad y^{10} \equiv 2 \pmod{3},$$
which is *false*. This leads to your contradiction later in the proof.

Replacing it by the *true* implication
$$3 x^{10}-y^{10} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}\qquad
\implies \qquad y^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{3},$$
does *not* lead to a contradiction later in the proof. So this approach will not work.

---

As suggested in the comments, working modulo $11$ is much more natural because it allows you to use Fermat's little theorem; you have $x^{11}\equiv x\pmod{11}$ for all $x$.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem will directly rule out all integer solutions except the case $x=11a,\ y=11b$. That case, however, leads to $11^9(3a^{10}-b^{10})=181$ which plainly is impossible, since $181$ does not have $11^9$ as one of its factors.